# Cannot find name 'global'

Tags: angular, jestjs

### Angular 15 Project using Jest Testing Framework Error

I have an Angular 15 project using jest (v28.1.3) for unit testing.

I'm trying to test a method that utilizes a `setTimeout()` function. According to the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/timer-mocks) it's as simple as

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
...
//call component method
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(function), 100)
```

When I try running this test using the code above I get the following in the console:

> FAIL  src/app/data-flow/data-flow.component.spec.ts   ● Test suite
> failed to run
>
> src/app/data-flow/data-flow.component.spec.ts:112:18 - error TS2304:
> Cannot find name 'global'.
>
> 112       jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       0 total Snapshots:   0
> total Time:        9.634 s Ran all test suites matching
> /data-flow.component/i.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install @types/node and use it in the compilerOption types besides "jest", because "global" is from node (inspired by the last answer to this issue: https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto/issues/70)

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
...}
```